# Удаленное подключение к БД Oracle через DBeaver - ORA-12514

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных Oracle с помощью DBeaver, но получаю ошибку:

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514,
> TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
> descriptor

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

С чем может быть связана и как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Попробуйте выбрать вместо `Service name` -> `SID` и войти используя данные tnsnames.ora в админке. (Выбор параметра находится справа от `База данных`: `ORCL`)

Comment: tnsnames.ora лежит на машине, на которой развернута БД?

Comment: ну да, обычно по пути `c:\oracle\network\admin`, но это не точно, я то не знаю как админ развернул бд

Comment: ну к dbeaver так написано -> https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Oracle#:~:text=TNS%20names%20path,oracle%5Cnetwork%5Cadmin . А по хорошему уточню свой коммент выше, путь до файла tnsnames.ora лежит в переменной среды TNS_ADMIN

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариев родился ответ. Необходимо выбрать вместо `Service name` -> `SID` и войти используя данные из `tnsnames.ora` в админке. [Путь до файла `tnsnames.ora` лежит в переменной среды `TNS_ADMIN`](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Oracle#:%7E:text=TNS%20names%20path,oracle%5Cnetwork%5Cadmin).